# Why did currying in Ruby fail to work in my code?

Tags: ruby, currying

My got an error message "method_object.rb:8:in `': wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Proc) (TypeError)" when trying to run the following script

```
def f(x,y=2)
  x**y
end

a=method(:f).to_proc  
b=a.curry.curry[4]

print 1.upto(5).map(&b)    
puts
```

However, if **function f** is defined in the following way, everything was OK.

```
def f(x,y)
  x**y
end
```

Would any one help me with what went wrong with my first code?

Answer (score 5):

[`Proc#curry`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-curry)

> Returns a curried proc. If the optional arity argument is given, it determines the number of arguments. A *curried* `proc` receives some arguments. If a *sufficient number* of arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the original `proc` and *returns the result*. Otherwise, returns another curried proc that takes the rest of arguments.

Now coming to your code :

```
def f(x, y=2)
  x**y
end

a = method(:f).to_proc  
b = a.curry.curry[4]
b.class # => Fixnum
b # => 16
print 1.upto(5).map(&b) 
# wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Proc) (TypeError)
```

Look the documentation now - A *curried* `proc` receives some arguments. If a s*ufficient number* of arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the original `proc` and *returns the result*.

In your code, when you did `a.curry`, it returns a *curried proc*. Why? Because your method `f` has *one optional* and *one required* argument, but you didn't provide any. Now you call again `a.curry.curry[4]`, so on the previous *curried proc* which is still waiting for at-least one argument, this time you gave to it by using `curry[4]`. Now *curried* `proc` object gets called with `4, 2` as arguments, and evaluated to a `Fixnum` object `8` and assigned to `b`. **b is not a proc object**, rather a `Fixnum` object.

Now, `1.upto(5).map(&b)` here - `&b` means, you are telling convert the `proc` object assgined to `b` to a block. But **NO**, `b` is not holding `proc` object, rather `Fixnum` object `8`. So Ruby **complains** to you.

Here the message comes as **wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Proc) (TypeError)**.

Now coming to your second part of code. Hold on!! :-)

Look below :

```
def f(x, y)
  x**y
end
a = method(:f).to_proc  
b = a.curry.curry[4]
b.class # => Proc
b # => #<Proc:0x87fbb6c (lambda)>
print 1.upto(5).map(&b) 
# >> [4, 16, 64, 256, 1024]
```

Now, your method `f` needs 2 mandatory argument `x, y`. `a.curry`, nothing you passed so a **curried proc** is returned. Again `a.curry.curry[4]`, humm you passed one required argument, which is `4` out of 2. So again a **curried proc** returned.

Now `1.upto(5).map(&b)`, same as previous `b` expects a `proc`, and you fulfilled its need, as now b is `proc` object. `&b` converting it to a block as below :

```
1.upto(5).map { |num| b.call(num) }
```

which in turn outputs as - `[4, 16, 64, 256, 1024]`.

**Summary**

Now suppose you defined a `proc` as below :

```
p = Proc.new { |x, y, z = 2| x + y + z }
```

Now you want to make `p` as *curried proc*. So you did `p.curry`. Remember you didn't pass any *arity* when called `curry`. Now point is a *curried proc* will wait to evaluate and return the result of `x + y + z`, unless and until, you are giving it all the required arguments it needs to produce it results.

That means `p.curry` gives you a *curried proc* object, then if you do `p.curry[1]` ( mean you are now passing value to `x` ), again you got a *curried proc*. Now when you will write `p.curry[1][2]`, all required arguments you passed ( mean you are now passing value to `y` ), so now `x + y + z` will be called.

Comment: Here's a related issue/feature request in the Ruby Bug Tracker: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4610

Comment: @p11y Code is behaving as per the doc I can see... :-)

Comment: Oh, now I have known where the error is. The optional argument 'y=2' makes b not a proc object! What a serious error! Thanks very much!

Comment: @user3477465 just a small addition here towards you, you do not need to curry a two times, you can simply do it once like b = a.curry[4].

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.map`, it requires a `block` of type `proc`. In your first case `b` returns `16` as `y=2` uses default value `2` for exponent when you are sending single argument using `curry`. `b` returning `16` is not a `proc` `object` and can not be used with `.map`.

`Curry` when used with a proc with `sufficient arguments`, it executes original proc and returns a result. Which is happening in OP's first case with curried proc passed with 4 as only argument and default `y=2 in f(x, y=2)` getting used and resulting in `16` as return value. 16 being `Fixnum` can not be used with enumerator `map` method.

`Curry` when used with insufficient arguments return a `proc`. So in case 2 when `f(x, y)` is used curried `a` is passed only single argument resulting in a `proc` object `{|e| 4 ** e}` being returned and which gets executed by `map` method.

Comment: No not *when you are sending single argument using curry*.. `curry` will return a `proc` object. then `curry[4]` means you are calling `Proc#[]` or `Proc#call` or `Proc#()`...on the *proc* object returned by `#curry`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes curry returns a proc object only when it is not supplied sufficient number of arguments otherwise curry executes the original proc and returns a result. In case 2, for f(x, y), x is 4 but y is not passed so a proc is returned by curry like Proc {|e| 4 ** e}

Comment: Yes, all I explained in my answer. I think I didn't left, still fixing typos there..